# How to make a percentual width to include the padding? border-box seems not to be working

Tags: html, css

I want to make a percentage width to include the padding. That is, if my `div` width is `50%` or `500px`, it should be `250px` regardless of the padding.

Here's the fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/sxzxbe2t/

As you can see here...

[image: kitty]

... the kitty is still `290px` wide while it should be `250px`. I'm using `box-sizing: border-box;` to no avail.

Any idea?

**EDIT**

I need the image to keep being 100% inside the div, unless there's another way for it to occupy the entire width.

Comment: It's 250 for me, what browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you still have to add vendor prefixes [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxzxbe2t/12/)

```
.container .image-wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 20px; 
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    box-sizing: border-box;  // this makes no difference
}
```

Comment: We should be able to use box-sizing without prefixing on Chrome in 2016. Thanks for spotting this.